# Can any web server identify private IP address

Tags: networking, web

I have a doubt regarding identification of private IP address outside private network.

The thing I know is after Network Address Translation(NAT), private IP does not go in packet to web server(public space). But I have noticed a couple of websites identify what is the private IP address of the user, I am confused how?

Comment: A private IP address is meaningless outside the private network. This is because there are many thousands of private networks using the same private IP addresses. An upper-layer protocol may grab the private IP address and stick it in the application data, but it is of no consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of proxies and load balancers, for example, the web server that finally receives and handles the request will think/see that the request came FROM the proxy or load balancer IP.

To pass along the originating IP address, those load balancers and proxies will often inject or add additional HTTP headers into the request to indicate the client's IP.  The web server will need to know to look for the header being used and include it in its server-side code or access-log files.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Ok, but if proxy servers are not trusted enough? I mean its only on the proxy server say that this is the originating IP address?